# @ActiveProfiles doesn't work with AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring

I introduced profiles in a Spring Boot application and I moved some properties from application.properties to application-puppet.properties. This works fine when running the application but not when testing.

Added this to the application.properties file:

```
spring.profiles.active=puppet
```

And moved one propert from application.properties to application-puppet.properties

```
person.fileName=person.txt
```

Then I add @ActiveProfiles to a abstract testclass:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes =  AbstractElasticsearchSpringContextTests.EsConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("puppet")
public abstract class AbstractElasticsearchSpringContextTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

...

But I get an error like this:
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'person.fileName' in string value "${person.fileName}"

Comment: And why should it load that property file? If you are using Spring Boot there is nothing spring boot related in there which will load the property file(s) based on the active profile. Nor are you using the Spring Boot support classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm new to Spring Boot and to the app I'm working with so I do not understand your comment. I did get the active profile to work in the Spring Boot app but it doesn't work in the tests. Somehow the tests only reads the properties in the application.properties file but not properties in the application-puppet.properties. I do not understand what Sprint Boot related that is missing.

Answer (score -1):

You can add SpringBootContextLoader as loader in your ContextConfiguration annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AbstractElasticsearchSpringContextTests.EsConfig.class}, loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
```

and it will take care of your active profile properties file.

Comment: @ Downvoter: Can you explain what is wrong with the answer?